# Adding Attributes And Starting Value To Python enum.IntEnum

Tags: python, enums

How can I define a Python enum class that somehow derives from `int`, has a custom starting value, and adds custom attributes?  I know how to derive from `int` using `enum.IntEnum` and set the starting value,

```
Goo = enum.IntEnum("Goo", "MOO FOO LOO", start = 42)
```

and how to add custom attributes to the base enum type,

```
class Goo(enum.Enum):
    MOO = (42, "forty-two")
    FOO = (43, "forty-three")
    LOO = (44, "forty-four")

    def __init__(self, value, alias):
        self._value = value   #self.value gives AttributeError, as expected, grrr...
        self.alias = alias
```

but how do I do all three?  I've tried all manner of `__new__()` too,

```
class Goo(int, enum.Enum):
    MOO = (42, "forty-two")
    FOO = (43, "forty-three")
    LOO = (44, "forty-four")

    def __new__(cls, value, alias):
        self = super().__new__(cls, value)
        self.alias = alias

        return self
```

mostly with odd errors,

```
TypeError: int() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

in this case.  Thanks.

Jim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior you want isn't already available in the stdlib `Enum`.  You could use `itertools.count()` to get the numbers:

```
from enum import IntEnum
from itertools import count

_goo_count = count(42)
class Goo(IntEnum):
    #
    MOO = "forty-two"
    FOO = "forty-three"
    LOO = "forty-four"
    #
    def __new__(cls, alias):
        value = next(_goo_count)
        member = int.__new__(cls, value)
        member._value_ = value
        member.alias = alias
        return member
```

or you can use `aenum`:

```
from aenum import IntEnum

class Goo(IntEnum):
    _start_ = 42
    _init_ = 'alias'
    #
    MOO = "forty-two"
    FOO = "forty-three"
    LOO = "forty-four"
```

either way, in use it looks like:

```
>>> Goo.MOO
<Goo.MOO: 42>

>>> Goo.MOO.alias
'forty-two'

>>> Goo.MOO == 42
True
```

A couple stylistic notes:

- you don't need parentheses to define a tuple

  - except for an empty tuple
  - or some place (like a function call), where the command would be interpreted as not a tuple
- white space is good  ;-)

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: Mine `does` have a ```__new__()```, and not an ```__init__()```.  The only real difference is that I called ```super().__new__()```, and you called ```int.__new__()```.  That gets rid of the error, but still doesn't let me specify a starting value.  I'd rather avoid listing the value of every enum, as I'm able to do in my first example.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: You also named the integer ```_value_```.  I didn't, but it's required by the metaclass.

Comment: @Jim:  Redid answer to get all three points: derives from `int`, has custom starting value, and has custom attributes.