# Type Hints For enum.IntEnum Class

Tags: python, enums

I'm trying to add type hints to a custom [enum.IntEnum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#intenum) with a particular starting value and attributes (discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64038885/adding-attributes-and-starting-value-to-python-enum-intenum)).  This is what seems right to me, but not to *mypy*.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import enum
import itertools

counter = itertools.count(42)

class Goo(enum.IntEnum):
   MOO = ("grr", 1.2)
   LOO = ("fzz", 3.4)

   def __new__(cls,label: str, size: float) -> Goo:
      value = next(counter)

      member = int.__new__(cls, value)

      member._value_ = value          # 16
      member.label   = label          # 17
      member.size    = size           # 18

      return member

assert isinstance(Goo.MOO, Goo)
assert isinstance(Goo.MOO, int)
assert Goo.MOO       == 42
assert Goo.MOO.label == "grr"         # 25
assert Goo.MOO.size  == 1.2           # 26
```

The program works as shown, but *mypy* gives me these errors, which I don't know how to fix.  I think the first comes from me changing the type of `_value_` after *mypy* has already decided what it is, and I don't think there's a way to change its mind.  I don't understand the others, which imply I can't add attributes to my own class.

```sh
% mypy goo
goo:16: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "int", variable has type "Tuple[str, float]")
goo:17: error: "Goo" has no attribute "label"
goo:18: error: "Goo" has no attribute "size"
goo:25: error: "Goo" has no attribute "label"
goo:26: error: "Goo" has no attribute "size"
```

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a better way, but it seems sufficient to provide hints for the two attributes statically.

```
class Goo(enum.IntEnum):
   label: str
   size: float

   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It seems to work, though I don't understand how.  I'd expect *mypy* to be able to discern what the types are from the assignments.  I also don't understand how it doesn't cause the two attributes to be interpreted as two more enums.  Regardless, the code still works and satisfies *mypy*.  I'll wait a bit before accepting this answer.

Comment: Part of the problem (I think) is that you don't really have any information about what `int.__new__` (a static method) will return, only that it's an instance of `cls`, and there's no way to know *statically* what `cls` will be. (Or, that `Goo` is anything other than an `int`; `EnumMeta` is a tricky metaclass that may upend a lot of the assumptions that `mypy` relies upon.)