# mypy Oddity With Python Enum Lookups

Tags: python, enums, mypy

I'm trying to write a custom [enum.IntEnum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#intenum) class that overrides the starting value and adds a string attribute (discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64038885/adding-attributes-and-starting-value-to-python-enum-intenum)).  *mypy* doesn't like when I look up enums by value.  See the two numbered lines near the bottom.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import enum
import itertools

gooCount = itertools.count(42)

class Goo(enum.IntEnum):
    FOO = "fzz",
    MOO = "mrp",

    label: str

    def __new__(cls, label: str) -> Goo:
        value = next(gooCount)

        mbr = int.__new__(cls, value)

        mbr._value_ = value
        mbr.label = label

        return mbr

foo = Goo(42)                 # line 23
assert foo == 42
assert foo is Goo.FOO
assert foo.label == "fzz"

moo = Goo(43)                 # line 28
assert moo == 43
assert moo is Goo.MOO
assert moo.label == "mrp"
```

The code runs fine, but *mypy* complains about those two lines, which look up particular enums by their integer value.

```sh
% mypy goo.py
goo.py:23: error: Argument 1 to "Goo" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str"
goo.py:28: error: Argument 1 to "Goo" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str"
```

I expect it's somehow confused about the metaclass magic in `enum`.  The `__init__()` method should probably be overloaded to accept an `int` for these lookups, or whatever additional types I'm adding, a `str` in this case.  Is there a way to fix these errors without `# type: ignore` or `typing.cast()`?

**Update 1**: I wasn't able to make those overloads explicit by adding this,

```py
<same as above>

from typing import Union, overload

<same as above>

class Goo(enum.IntEnum):

    <same as above>

    @overload
    def __init__(self, arg: int) -> None: ...

    @overload
    def __init__(self, arg: str) -> None: ...

    def __init__(self, arg: Union[int, str]) -> None:
        if isinstance(arg, int):
            super().__init__(arg)                       # line 32
        else:
            self.label = arg

<same as above>
```

That gives me this.

```sh
% mypy goo.py
goo.py:32: error: Too many arguments for "__init__" of "object"
```

**Update 2**: Calling `enum.IntEnum.__init__()` instead of `super().__init__()` on line 32 still runs and appeases *mypy*, but that was arrived at by trial and error, not understanding.  Also, I can't seem to even reach that line, so this "works" too.  That makes it appear as though the possibility of an `int` is entirely artificial, there just for *mypy*.

```py
<same as above>

from typing import Union

<same as above>

class Goo(enum.IntEnum):

    <same as above>

    def __init__(self, arg: Union[int, str]) -> None:
        assert not isinstance(arg, int)
        self.label = arg

<same as above>
```

Is this my answer?  Why?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like [a limitation](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/10573) of *mypy*.  The best answer I can find is the `__init__()` hack I mentioned in **Update 2**, repeated here but in full.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import enum
import itertools

goo_count = itertools.count(42)

class Goo(enum.IntEnum):
    FOO = "fzz",
    MOO = "mrp",

    label: str

    def __new__(cls, label: str) -> Goo:
        value = next(goo_count)

        mbr = int.__new__(cls, value)

        mbr._value_ = value
        mbr.label = label

        return mbr

    def __init__(self, arg: int) -> None:
        assert isinstance(arg, str)  # enum by-value lookups do not call __init__()

foo = Goo(42)
assert foo == 42
assert foo is Goo.FOO
assert foo.label == "fzz"

moo = Goo(43)
assert moo == 43
assert moo is Goo.MOO
assert moo.label == "mrp"
```

I'm not accepting this as the answer since it's just a workaround.  Hopefully, *mypy* will eventually learn this [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes) use case of enums.